# If conditional with Async inside looping

Tags: javascript, mysql, asynchronous

For example, I'm using MySQL modules in here. This is my script:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  function ExecuteQuery() {
    connection.query("SELECT balance FROM user WHERE id = 1", function(err, result) {
      if (result[0].balance < 1000) {
        connection.query("UPDATE user SET balance = 100000 WHERE id = 1", function(err, result) {
          console.log("Balance is update")
        })
      } else {
        console.log("Done")
        return
      }
    })
  }
  ExecuteQuery()
}
})
```

So, the result is:

```js
1. Balance is update
2. Balance is update
3. Balance is update
```

What I want is for the first step to update the balance, and the second step should then show a "Done" message and stop the loop.

So, the result becomes

```
1. Balance is updated
2. Done
```

Also, I was trying to use a while-loop but that method doesn't work either. How come?

Thanks.

Comment: I would avoid showing your MySQL queries in JavaScript. Is this Node?

Comment: @PHPglue JavaScript is also server-side.

Comment: Yeah, then it's called Node.

Comment: @AdeFirmanFauzi Why do you need a loop ? What do you want to achieve ? What's the point of executing 2 times the request ?

Comment: @PHPglue, oh yeah sorry. I forgot to input node tags in here.

Comment: The query is async, it will be executed 3 times before the first result is done. You will need to restructure the code completely

Comment: Is it because `result[0].balance` should be cast to a number like `if(+result[0].balance < 1000)`? Results from MySQL fetching function properties are Strings.

Comment: @NathanP. The main goal is check balance after updating the balance

Comment: You have figured out a very complicated way of doing a very simple thing. With a single SQL statement, `UPDATE user SET balance = 100000 WHERE id = 1 AND balance < 1000;` none of this complex JS setup is even necessary.

Comment: @Tomalak is right. You should also check the `err` variable. If it's `false` or `undefined` then you data IS updated, there's no need to check it then.

Comment: Is it Working nicely right now?. If it does, please let us know by providing answers to this question.